# How can I peek the tail of a java.util.PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, heap, priority-queue

So I am playing with the source code of the `java.util.PriorityQueue`. You can check it here: http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/PriorityQueue.java.htm

I am in need to peek the tail of the queue. This class only offers peeking the head of the queue. Is there an easy way that I can modify this class to allow me to pick the tail?

I am looking for any change / smart hack in this class to allow me to do that. My first try was to peek `queue[size]` but it did not work.

Comment: take a look at [Guava's MinMaxPriorityQueue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/src/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.java?r=dd96b4930181fc70bd7c90beded3a272f251db35)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's PriorityQueue, like most priority queues, is implemented with a heap.

A heap is a data structure that maintains only the property that all parents are less than their children, or all parents are greater than their children. There is no inherent ordering among children.

Thus, the only way to find the tail would be to do a linear search among the bottom layer, which costs `O(n)` time for a size `n` priority queue.

Comment: I thought the PriorityQueue was sorted, so that tail (biggest value) must be somewhere. No?

Comment: @MichelleQueen, No, it is not fully sorted. It only maintains *either* the minimum *or* the maximum at the top. The other end is somewhere among the last `n/2` elements in the `queue` array.

Comment: I guess I will just save the max value as I am offering. What do you think?

Comment: @MichelleQueen, If you mean saving the last remaining element as you offer it, you can certainly do that. Depending on what you are trying to do, that may or may not be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the at the cost of extra space complexity:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pqNew = new PriorityQueue<>(java.util.Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Now add the elements of your `PriorityQueue` into this `pqNew`.
Therefore, `pqNew.peek()` will give you the required answer i.e. the tail element of your original `PriorityQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

How about use toArray() method and access the last position?

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(3);
pq.offer(1); pq.offer(2); pq.offer(3);
System.out.println((int) pq.toArray()[pq.size()-1]);
```